# how to enable c++ support in visual studio 2010?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

I want to create a C++ project in Visual studio 2010 but I don't 
see any template for a C++ project. All I see is visual c# templates.
Please let me know how to enable c++ support in visual studio  2010.

Comment: Do you see an "Other languages" tab in "New Project"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You likely have Visual Studio installed without the C++ compiler. You have to start the installer and alter the installation so that C++ compiler is installed.

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to reinstall it.  During installation there is a choice of languages and features.  Probably C++ was not chosen when it was installed on your system.